# Get route data with route url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I wanted to do a permissions system, where I saved what permissions a user has to have in order to access a certain URL.

Like this:

```
{ path: '/path/to/page', canActivate: [CustomGuard], data: {'permissions': ['can_edit','can_delete']}}
```

The Guard works fine, I can access the route data through there. But now I want to hide some items from the menu, based on these permissions.

So I was thinking about creating a method that recieves a url (`/path/to/page`) and then compare the user's permissions with the route permissions. Something like this:

```
canAccess(url: string) {
    const data = getRouteData(url); // I need this method
    return compare(this.userPermissions, data['permissions']) // true or false
}
```

But I still haven't found how to access the route data from a url. I really need help!

Answer (score 1):

You can access routes array using `Router`:

```
  constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log(router.config);
  }
```

There you can read `data` attribute. However you this approach will not work for lazy loaded modules. Also you will have to match URL on your own.

Afaik there is no way to get this info from the router. Instead I would suggest you to implement permission system which can be used both by guards and by directives hiding/showing links.

Or use existing solution like [ngx-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

What you can use then is a [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), basically what it helps you with is to before actually routing to the route, handle what ever you want to before actually rendering anything. So basically inject a Service to the resolver and then use the same service in the Menu component your using.

**UPDATE**

As discussed in comments what you can then in your guard is simply inject your permission service as following example (note the services in the constructor):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private userPermissions: PermissionService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {


        if (compare(this.userPermissions.permissions, route.config.data.permissions) ) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private compare(userPermissions:any, routePermissions): boolean {
        // compare permissions and return true or false
    }
}
```

Then to read the permissions once routing is done, use Router service injected either to your component or service like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page1',
  templateUrl: './page1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page1.component.css']
})
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {

  public permissions: Data;

  constructor(private route: Router) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.permissions = this.route.config[1].data.permissions;
  }

}
```

heres a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-router-data-example) to view it in action

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, can you explain a little bit more how to achieve this?

Comment: sure, give me a few to fix an example

Comment: Actually i reserve my answer reading again your question. As I assume you already know the user permissions for the route in the app client? If so do you have it in a service that you can inject it to the guard service?

Comment: imho resolver wont help you because the user didnt navigate to the route yet when the link is visible.

Comment: @Martin yes exactly why I reserved my answer as you already know the users permissions?

Comment: Yes, I already know the user permissions. I have them on a permissions service. I also have the routes permissions but inside the route data on the AppRouting Module. Also, thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I see what you did. As I said in my question, I can actually do the permissions check on the Guard. What I want to do is to get the permissions of a route with the url only, from a component so I can hide menu options

Comment: @JCAguilera ok in addition to whats established, after you routed you want to read the permissions from the URL e.g. _'www.base.com/page2;foo=foo;bar=bar'_ or do you want to read the data attribute with permissions from _{ path: '/path/to/page', canActivate: [CustomGuard], data: {'permissions': ['can_edit','can_delete']}}_ ?

Comment: Well I first have an anchor tag with a router link attribute. I want to use that router link url to get the "_{ path: '/path/to/page', canActivate: [CustomGuard], data: {'permissions': ['can_edit','can_delete']}}_" object, and then get the permissions from there.

Comment: @JCAguilera Then you can do as Martin_Nuc mentioned and just inject to any component or service to retrieve the data, updated the response again with code